# Actual length of input vector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

i am running a HDL code written in VHDL and i have an input vector with maximum length of 512 bits. Some of my inputs are less than the max size. So i want to find if there is a way to find the actual length of every input, in order to cut the unwanted zeros at the most significant bits of the input vector. Is there any possible way to do this kind of stuff?

Comment: Could you please give some example inputs and the expected outputs. Also post the required signal / variable declariations.

Comment: In addition please show the code you have tried to far, so an answer can fit you specific requirements, since the option space is otherwise very wide.

Comment: The length is determinable knowing whether it's an ascending or descending range. A non-synthesis eligible function is easy - `function getlen (inp: bit_vector) return integer is alias input:  bit_vector (inp'length - 1 downto 0) is inp; begin for i in input'range loop if input(i) /= '0' then return input(i downto 0)'LENGTH;  end if; end loop; return 0; end function;` Describing a 512 bit priority encoder  for synthesis and the hardware to take advantage of it a bit more complex. Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for an unambiguous padding method for your data. What I would recommend in your case is an adaption of the ISO/IEC 9797-1 padding method 2 as follows:

For every input data (even if it already has 512 bits), you add a leading '1' bit. Then you add leading '0' bits (possibly none) to fill up your vector.

To implement this scheme you would have to enlargen your input vector to 513 bits (because you have to **always** add at least one bit).

To remove the padding, you simple go through the vector starting at the MSB and find the first '1' bit, which marks the end of your apdding pattern.

Example (for 8+1 bit):

input:  10101

padded: *0001* 10101

input:  00000000

padded: *1* 00000000